# Exponential lower bound for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Can someone show me how to solve through induction, $F(N) \geq (3/2)^N$ for all $N\geq N_0$, where $F(n)$ is the Fibonacci function and $N_0$ is some positive integer. I know that $N_0$ should be $11$, but I can't find the constant or show the proof correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? The possibility of an inductive proof suggests that perhaps $f(n+1) \ge \frac{3}{2}f(n)$. Does this appear to be true? Do you see a reason? Given that $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)$ after the first couple of terms, do you see anything helpful to consider?

Comment: Your induction assumption is that $F_n$ **and** $F_{n-1}$ satisfy the inequality. You conclude that $F_{n+1}$ and $F_n$ satisfy the inequality. Of course the $F_n$ part is trivial from the induction assumption.

Comment: I know that the induction step is to show that Fn+1 + fn satisfy the inequality I don't know how to go about proving it

Comment: I've edited a bit, but the part about $N_0=11$ doesn't seem to make sense. One has $F(0)=0$, so I would say that violates you inequality right away; it might however hold for large $N$. The point of setting $N_0=11$ (what is $N_0$ anyway) really escapes me.

Comment: F(n) is greater then (3/2)^2 when n = 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So. I'm going to assume that $F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1$, but you may need to recast this based on whatever convention you'd like to use.

Proceeding by strong induction, I'm going to use the base case $$F(11) = 89 \geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{11}, F(12) = 144 \geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{12}.$$

Now for the inductive step. Suppose that $F(k) \geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k}$ for all $11 \leq k \leq n$. Now $$ F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1) \geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n} + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1} = \frac{5}{2} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$
Now $\frac{5}{2} > \frac{9}{4}$, so
$$F(n+1) \geq \frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
which completes the proof. The main subject that may be unfamiliar is the difference between weak and strong induction. In weak induction, we prove that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ for all $n \geq n_0$; in strong induction, we prove that $P(i) \; \forall i \in \{n_0 \ldots n\} \implies P(n+1)$. Happily, these two methods of induction are logically equivalent, proof of which is a nice exercise.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! Quick question though isn't f(10) = 55 not 89, if we say f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1?

Comment: You are quite correct! Correcting now.

Comment: can you explain the line where we get 5/2(3/2)^n−1.

Comment: (3/2)^n = (3/2)*(3/2)^(n-1). The two ^(n-1) terms can be combined. So in the full formula you end up with ((3/2) + 1)*(3/2)^(n-1). ((3/2) + 1) = (5/2) as the final result above.